# Triple-wrapping of \colorbox → \NewEnviron → \newenvironment fails

Tags: latex

I am trying to wrap an environment created with `\NewEnviron` (package 'environ') into an old good `\newenvironment`:

```
\NewEnviron{test}{\colorbox[gray]{0.7}{\BODY}}
\newenvironment{wrapper}{\begin{test}}{\end{test}}

\begin{wrapper}
debug me
\end{wrapper}
```

However, this gives me a strange error:

> LaTeX Error: \begin{test} on input line 15 ended by \end{wrapper}.
>   LaTeX Error: \begin{wrapper} on input line 15 ended by \end{document}.

If I replace `\NewEnviron{test}{aaa(\BODY)bbb}` with `\newenvironment{test}{aaa(}{)bbb}` — everything works as expected! It seems like `\NewEnviron` fails to find its end for some reason.

I'm trying to do some magic with 'floatfig' wrapped into a `\colorbox` so I need a way to convert `\colorbox` to an environment and wrap it into another one. I can define a new command but it's not a very good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing is that `\NewEviron` and `\newenvironment` works in different ways.

1) `\newenvironment{test}{aaa(}{)bbb}` defines two commands: `\test` is `aaa(` and `\endtest` is `)bbb`.

`\begin{test}` is expanded to `\test`.

`\end{test}` is expanded to `\endtest` and checks that your scope begins with `begin{test}` rather `\begin{something else}`, for example `\begin{wrapper}`.

2) `\NewEviron{test}{aaa(\BODY)bbb}` defines `\test` in different way. First of all `\test` catches the `\BODY` using the following trick

```
\def\test#1\end{\def\BODY{#1}aaa(\BODY)bbb\testcontinue}
```

(name `\testcontinue` may be different) and inserts `aaa(\BODY)bbb`. Then `\testcontinue` checks that `\end` on some input line ended by `\end{test}` rather than `\end{something else}`. Macro `\endtest`
is not needed because it is never executed.

Look on your code:

```
\begin{wrapper}
debug me               
\end{wrapper}
```

`\begin{wrapper}` is expanded to `\begin{test}`. Then
`\begin{test}` is expanded to `\test`. `\test` catch `\BODY`. 
Attention! `\BODY` is equal to `debug me`. And now `\testcontionue` checks
that `\end` after `\BODY` ended by `\end{test}`. It is not true. `\end{test}` is absent.
There is `\end{wrapper}`.

You want to say that `\end{wrapper}` must be expanded to `\end{test}`. But `\end` before wrapper was eaten by

```
macro \test: #1\end{\def\BODY{#1}aaa(\BODY)bbb\testcontinue}
```

and can not be executed.

I hope I success to explain.

Comment: Your explanation is great, thank you! I guess that means I can't wrap it into another environment? or maybe there's a trick I'm not aware of?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `\newenvironment`?

Comment: I need to create an environmental version of `\colorbox` and have no idea how to do it :)

Comment: accepted: w/out your explanations I would have failed. Спасибо, земляк! :)

Comment: +1 Excellent explanation.  I had looked at the NewEnviron code and couldn't figure out Will's freaky staging of his arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a hacky trick to create an environment that can be wrapped in another one. One should use saveBoxes like this:

```
\newenvironment{example}[2][]{%
    \newsavebox{\exampleStore} % Box storage
    \begin{lrbox}{\exampleStore} % Start capturing the input
    }{%
        \end{lrbox} % Stop capturing the input
    \colorbox[gray]{0.7}{%
            \usebox{\NBstorage} % Load the box's contents
            }%
        }%
    }%
```